# Java : Accepting command line arguments for array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, command-line-arguments

I have an array like of objects in my main

```
Number[] NumberArray;
```

The class Item has this definition:

```
public class Number {
    int a1;
    int a2;
}
```

I need to accept input from command line like say 1 2 3 4 5 6, such that

```
Number[1].a1 = 2
```

and

```
Number[1].a2 = 3
```

and

```
Number[4].a1 = 5
```

and

```
Number[4].a2 = 6.
```

How do I do this?

Please help.

Comment: For starters, your requirement is super strange.  Why are you skipping entries in the array?  You also don't do anything with `Number[0]`, which is the first entry in the array.  To that end, when you write `public static void main(String[] args)`, `args` would hold `1 2 3 4 5 6`.  Have you attempted anything to parse that array in your program?  If you did, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

In your main method:

`public static void main(String[] args)`

`args` is an array of command line parameters. To convert a String to an int, use `Integer.valueOf()`.

For example, to get the integer value of the first commandline argument do the following:

```
Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
```

Note that this will crash if there are no arguments.

Comment: valueOf() returns Integer, which would then auto-unboxed to int, but cleaner to use parseInt()